# How to assign two IP Adresses on one ethernet Port?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am using Ubuntu Bionic and here is what I am trying to do. One device has two IP Addresses say for example 192.168.1.20 and 192.168.250.20 (These IP addresses are from two different Network Interfaces present inside the device)  Now I want to connect this device to my computer. For that I use a single Ethernet Cable and connect the Ethernet ports of two devices.  On the Interface where I connect my Ethernet cable, I assign two IP addresses 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.250.10.

Now when I try to ping 192.168.1.20 from 192.168.250.20 (these are IP Addresses from the other device, which I want to connect to)  from my Computer, it works just fine. However, when I try to ping 192.168.1.10 from my other device. It does not work. I can only ping 192.168.250.10.

I have limited knowledge about networking, and I have no idea what is wrong. If I assign only one IP-Address 192.168.1.20 to my Computer, I still cannot ping it. So I have no idea, what could be the cause for it.

The device runs on embedded windows and my Computer runs on Ubuntu.
How do I go on about troubleshooting it? I would be thankful for any pointer.

Comment: In a situation with 2 separate NICs, you would need a static route(s)... the pings may be leaving(or not), maybe even received(or not), but at some point the sender or receiver does not know where to direct the traffic due to the gateway(s)... But I'm not sure if one NIC with two IP is self-aware of routing though... When I did this(long ago) I configured a virtual NIC on the same interface and it was like its own separate device that I configured routing for... that may be what you need, if static routes alone dont work... you didnt say much about the physical architecture, which is useful

Answer (score 0):

In order to have multiple network interfaces on one ethernet port you will have to take advantage of VLANs.
In order to have VLANs working, you have to have a network switch that supports this feature. (Managed switch with VLAN tagging features).

To have the same functionality without needing to use VLANs, I would recommend upgrading to a different network card, which supports multiple ethernet interfaces.